# Node JS chunk files reading as one file without interrupt?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I successfully read m3u8 and extract ts files and read m3u8 and check if new indexes are written to it (ts files) and then using

```
res.write(chunk);
```

i get stream without interrupting..it is reading files in order that was defined in m3u8 file and all is working flawlessly...but i have one HUGE problem...using res.write i im getting that my chunk ts files are read from HDD to RAM and RAM usage is incresed every seconds by 1MB so in about one hour i will get into out of memory...so the question is how can i erase previus read ts files from RAM so that memory usage will remain all the time same?

I see that res.write is writing to memory but is not deleting old data from memory..and this way is not practical and will get out of memory errors.Can i use for res.write buffers size so when buffer size is full automatically get erased from memory and read next chunk data to RAM?

Here is the code:

```
fs.readFile('/tmp/files/'+ts[ts.length-2], function (err, data ) {
    res.write(data);
    /* HERE I NEED TO CLEAR DATA BUFFER CHUNK FROM MEMORY */
});
```

So i read 1000 files in loop (small chunks) and write it to response to client...this works excellent without interrupting...but memory usage is file size read on HDD so RAM usage is growing...how can i delete data from memory after they is send to client?

Comment: `combined-stream` could help here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/combined-stream

Comment: thanks...but this is not what i need...i have ffmpeg that is making m3u8 file with indexed inside (1_0.ts, 1_1.ts...) and is refreshing on the fly...i read m3u file and get this indexes out..so i need to streram file without interrupitng...see apple hls streaming...

Comment: How is `combined-stream` not fulfilling your requirements?

Comment: I updated question using combined-stream..if you can please check it...i try but i im not getting any output from pipe(res)....thanks

Comment: Could you change your question so that it reads like you're asking your final question without all of the rest of the stuff. When I saw your title, I assumed this would be a question about reading multiple files as one, but now it looks like you're asking about memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found solution..i just need to add when i run my test.js on node:

```
node --expose-gc test.js
```

And before reading stream from file on HDD i added:

```
global.gc();
```

This way global.gc(); when run releases all memory that is read from function fs.filereadsync...so my code looks like this:

```
global.gc();
fs.readFile('/tmp/files/'+ts[ts.length-2], function (err, data ) {
   res.write(data);
```

});

This way...RAM usage when starting node js is the same all the time...it does not depends on how file chunk is large...it reads large file to memory..and when called again this function it releases ram to start state and read another chunk file on RAM and so in loop...